# Create a json response containing array of array

Tags: java, jackson-databind, fasterxml

Response required

```
{
  "data" : [[1234, 55],[1264,45],[1334, 56]]
}
```

Model

```
Class Timeseries{
  private List<List<Integer>> data;
}
```

I don't feel List of List is appropriate to achive the json response required.. But  I am unable to replace it with List, where CustomObject will contain 2 integer member variables.  As it will change the format of the response and send the response as data containing list of objects of type CustomObject instead of list of list..

Please suggest an alternate approch

Comment: What's wrong with list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reach your needed output is

```
class data extends ArrayList<List<Integer>> {
}
```

and use this code for serilization with Jackson JSON

```
data ts = new data();
ts.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1234, 55), Arrays.asList(1264, 45), Arrays.asList(1334, 56)));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ts);

System.out.println(result);
```

The output string will be as you need `{"data":[[1234,55],[1264,45],[1334,56]]}`

But, seriously, the right way here is to implement for

```
class Timeseries {
    private List<List<Integer>> data;
}
```

your own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer<T>` successor for `Timeseries` class.

**UPDATE:**

Just find out the easiest way to reach your needed string for class

```
class Timeseries {
   public List<List<Integer>> data;
}
```

*Note `data` field has to be either `public` or have a getter.*

And then code

```
Timeseries ts = new Timeseries();
ts.data = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1234, 55), Arrays.asList(1264, 45), Arrays.asList(1334, 56));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ts);
System.out.println(result);
```

will print `{"data":[[1234,55],[1264,45],[1334,56]]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
class CustomObject {
    private int data1;
    private int data2;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Then you can modify your Timeseries as below,

```
private List<CustomObject> data;
```

Comment: won't that get you ```[ { ... }, { ... }, ... ]``` instead of what was wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of Arrays of size 2.